# Parsing Array of Objects with JQ

Tags: shell, jq

I am calling a curl request and receiving the data as an Array of Json Objects. I want to use this array of JSON Objects as a value in other JSON. This second JSON will be sent as a Request Body of an api call.

Response recieved from the curl request

```
[
    {
        id:1,
        "term":"term1"
    },
    {
        id:2,
        "term":"term2"
    },
    {
        id:3,
        "term":"term3"
    }
]
```

I am contructing the new json with the help of jq and I am parsing the array of JSON as --arg. So because of this the array gets parsed as string so my question is how can I pass the array in the JSON so that it does not get escape characters i.e. does not get parsed as string.

Comment: Use `--argjson`. But you'll need valid json, which you do not show here.

Comment: yes it is not a valid json and I want to use this array of objects only is there any other way of parsing this with jq

Comment: Be it with the `--argjson` option or the `fromjson` filter, jq can only parse valid JSON as JSON. You can, however, manually parse any literal string, even character by character if you need to.

Comment: @pmf so there is no way to parse this ?

Comment: Not with jq (if you don't want to do it manually), but there are plenty of other cli tools like [hjson](https://github.com/hjson/hjson-py) for example, perfectly suited for this task.

Comment: @pmf 0stone0 - Please consider rephrasing your responses in light of the -f technique.

Comment: Rephrased my comment into an answer as it became out of bounds for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jq to transform small quasi-JSON texts such as shown by treating it as a program, e.g. along the following lines:

```
function text {
    cat<<EOF
[
    {
        id:1,
        "term":"term1"
    },
    {
        id:2,
        "term":"term2"
    },
    {
        id:3,
        "term":"term3"
    }
]
EOF
}

jq -n -f <(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

jq can generally only parse JSON-encoded data as JSON if it is valid JSON.
This is how jq reads from STDIN, an input file, or when using the `--argjson`, `--jsonargs`, `--argfile`, or `--slurpfile` options.
If your input is initially interpreted as raw string data (by using the `--raw-input`, `--rawfile`, `--arg`, or `--args` options), you can still use the `fromjson` filter from within your jq code on JSON-encoded strings to parse them but a valid encoding is still required.

If your input data is not valid JSON (see https://www.json.org/ for a full specification), your options depend on how (much) it differs from JSON. Here are some of them:

- jq has many built-in functions to handle string data, so you could write anything from a converter to JSON that addresses your specific format violations, to a full-blown interpreter tailored to your overall target objectives. This is, of course, true to any capable programming language, I just wanted to point out that jq is indeed one them, and could infact be a reasonable choice if you already have jq code for a subsequent processing of your input.
- The jq language itself is a superset of JSON, and your sample data happens to be valid jq code. So, you could use jq to interpret your data as code, although this is generally regarded bad practice when processing unknown input data, especially in a production environment). See @peak's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76916385/2158479) for an example.
- YAML is also a superset of JSON, and your sample data also happens to be valid YAML data (so you could use any YAML interpreter to at least parse the input), but in this case the wording of `id:1` would not be interpreted as a value `1` under key `id` but rather as an undefined value under key `id:1`. (If there was a space between `id:` and `1`, it would, however). Nevertheless, you could still attempt to use a tool that either just converts YAML to JSON, or directly processes YAML the way you wanted to process the (almost valid) JSON input, and fix the issue with `id:1` on the go. Despite the more effort, this is, generally speaking, still better practice since the YAML data is still treated as data, not as code.

  - [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) (kislyuk's implementation) is a YAML processor that is built on top of jq. It converts the YAML input into JSON, then invokes jq to process it. The advantage with this solution is that you can use your original jq code without limitations. Here's how to fix the `id:1` issue (drop `| tonumber` if the value should remain a string):

    ```bash
    yq 'map(with_entries(
      select(.key | startswith("id:")) |= {key: "id", value: (.key[3:] | tonumber)}
    ))' invalid.json
    ```
  - [gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq) is a rewrite of jq in Go with some additional features, including a YAML interpreter that can be activated using the `--yaml-input` option. Its language is quasi-identical to jq's (some [minor differences](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq#difference-to-jq) exist, though), so the same fix can be applied and virtually the same advantage can be taken with this solution.

    ```bash
    gojq --yaml-input 'map(with_entries(
      select(.key | startswith("id:")) |= {key: "id", value: (.key[3:] | tonumber)}
    ))' invalid.json
    ```
  - [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) (mikefarah's implementation) is another YAML processor, built with jq in mind yet independently of it. Thus, their languages by design share many similarities but are not always interchangable. So, with this solution, the fix is somewhat different (drop `| . tag = "!!int"` if the value should remain a string), and re-using your original jq code may also be limited.

    ```bash
    yq -py -oj 'map(
      ."id:*" |= (key | sub("...", "") | . tag = "!!int" | key = "id")
    )' invalid.json
    ```
- [Hjson](https://github.com/hjson/hjson-py) is a syntax extension to JSON. It describes itself as "a user interface for humans, to read and edit before passing the JSON data to the machine". As such, it allows for features disallowed by JSON (like comments), and your sample data happens to be covered. This solution also treats the input as data.

  ```bash
  hjson -j invalid.json
  ```